# How to decide of whether to switch long-running tasks to another thread in your library or leave it to the user (developer)?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm creating an Android library. Should I switch long-running tasks to another thread, or is it better to let the user (developer) make that choice? My library uses Android SDK, Retrofit, Room, and Coroutines. I asked Gemini, but I want to listen to real developers and their practise

By Gemini.
Whether it's better to handle long-running tasks within your library or leave it to the user depends on several factors. Here's a breakdown of both approaches:

Handling long-running tasks within your library:

Pros:

Simplicity: Developers don't need to worry about thread management, avoiding potential concurrency issues.
Consistency: Ensures all users perform the tasks in the same way, potentially improving performance and reliability.
Optimization: The library can leverage its knowledge of internal structures to optimize thread usage or scheduling.
Cons:

Limited flexibility: Users might lose control over how tasks are executed, limiting customization.
Increased complexity: Your library becomes more complex, requiring more maintenance and testing.
Potential performance trade-offs: Using threads might not always be the most efficient, depending on the task.
Leaving it to the user:

Pros:

Flexibility: Developers can tailor thread usage to their specific needs and constraints.
Simplicity of your library: Your library remains focused on its core functionality.
Potential performance gains: Users might leverage specific knowledge of their applications to achieve better performance.
Cons:

Complexity for developers: Requires developers to understand thread management, increasing potential for errors.
Inconsistent behavior: Different implementations could lead to different outcomes and performance variations.
Possible resource hogging: Users might overuse threads, impacting overall system performance.
Coroutines considerations:

In the context of coroutines, the decision gets even more nuanced. Coroutines offer a lightweight alternative to threads, allowing cooperative multitasking instead of true concurrency. This has both benefits and drawbacks:

Benefits:

More efficient resource usage: Coroutines require fewer resources than threads, reducing overhead.
Better responsiveness: Switching between coroutines is faster than between threads, improving user experience.
Drawbacks:

Limited parallelism: Coroutines are not truly parallel, so they cannot benefit from multiple CPU cores.
Blocking coroutines: Blocking operations within coroutines can still lock the thread, requiring further consideration.
Ultimately, the best approach depends on your specific library and its goals.

Here are some additional factors to consider:

Target audience: Who are your users? Are they experienced developers comfortable with thread management, or do they need simpler solutions?
Nature of long-running tasks: Are they CPU-bound, I/O-bound, or a mix? This impacts the suitability of threads or coroutines.
Performance requirements: Do you prioritize raw performance or resource efficiency?
By carefully evaluating these factors, you can make an informed decision about the best approach for your library and its users. Remember, you can also offer a combination of options, allowing experienced users to manage threads themselves while providing simpler, managed solutions for others.

I hope this helps!